# May acheinu be said without a minyan?

Tags: tefilla, minyan

May the prayer of אַחֵינוּ כָּל בֵּית יִשְׂרָאֵל be said without a minyan?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: @RabbiK it's in plural

Comment: @DoubleAA Most tefillos are.

Comment: @DoubleAA by that logic a yahid could never recite the 'amidah

Comment: @DoubleAA is either joking, offering a hava amina on the questioner's behalf, or has seen something in hilchot tefilla that is rare

Comment: Is the question whether it's said on Monday and Thursday mornings without a minyan, even though it's usually said after the Torah reading which needs a minyan?

Comment: @Loani no, I was just wondering because I don't think I've ever heard anyone say it after a non-communal tehillim saying.

Comment: Oh. Well it's not "davar shebek'dusha" and it doesn't even have HaShems name, so there isn't any reason I can think of not to say it whenever you want